# How to pass multiple arguments to CallObjectMethod from C++ using JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to pass three strings to a java static method using JNI but I couldn't find how to do it. I am able to pass a single string as input, but it is not clear how to pass multiple parameters.Can you please help?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    JavaVM *vm;
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;

    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Algorithm\\output";
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 1;

    // Construct a VM
    jint res = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);

    jclass clazz_algo = env->FindClass("systems/DataExchange");
    if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
        return 1;
    }

    // init(String, String, String)
    jmethodID initMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz_algo, "init", "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    //HOW DO I CALL initMethod with three strings as input?

    // Shutdown the VM.
    vm->DestroyJavaVM();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html): `NativeType Call<type>Method(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
jmethodID methodID, ...);` _"Programmers **place all arguments that are to be passed to the method immediately following the `methodID` argument**. The `Call<type>Method` routine accepts these arguments and passes them to the Java method that the programmer wishes to invoke."_

Answer (score 3):

```
//HOW DO I CALL initMethod with three strings as input?
// Those are created as example
jstring str1=NewStringUTF(env, "Str1");
jstring str2=NewStringUTF(env, "Str2");
jstring str3=NewStringUTF(env, "Str3");

// C++ style
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(clazz_algo, initMethod, str1,str2,str3);
// ... or C-style
CallStaticVoidMethod(env, clazz_algo, initMethod, str1,str2,str3);
```